# Android Studio Error: "Cannot find variable itemclicklistener", despite having already imported OnItemClickListener API

Tags: android, api, import

Why does Android Studio not recognize that I already imported the onClickListener API?

Error in the following line:
listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

```
Code for my main activity is below:
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView,
                                    View v,
                                    int position,
                                    long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    //main activity launches food categories when the food option is clicked
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            FoodCategories.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };

        //Add the listener to my listview
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_options);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

        }
}
```

Comment: Where are you initialising your variable?

Comment: you need to define `itemClickListener`...!!

Comment: Thank you!  I feel foolish.  Its been a long day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView,
                                    View v,
                                    int position,
                                    long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    //main activity launches food categories when the food option is clicked
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            FoodCategories.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };
```

You have to create a variable before using it

Answer (score 1):

You haven't assigned `itemClickListener:

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = {rest of your code}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a initialization problem,This is a proper way.. Please check it.
May I could help you.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Add the listener to my listview
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_options);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

        }


       AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView,
                                    View v,
                                    int position,
                                    long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    //main activity launches food categories when the food option is clicked
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            FoodCategories.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView,
                                        View v,
                                        int position,
                                        long id) {
                    if (position == 0) {
                        //main activity launches food categories when the food option is clicked
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                FoodCategories.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            };


            ListView listView  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_options);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);                
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this..

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){/*your code here*/ }
```